# How to describe someone who is hiding behind a wall that is part of a turn in an alley?

Tags: sentence-construction

Someone is walking down an alley. At the end of the alley, there is only a turn to the left. He heard a noise up ahead. To describe the situation, is it correct to say: "***He hid around the corner of the alley and took a peek.***" to describe that he hid behind the wall of the turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can say that. But it is wordy.

> He peeked round the corner of the alley

already conveys the idea of hiding.